# Place Panels that might resize automatically

Tags: winforms, panel, tablelayout

My design is like this: I have some panels, say Panel1, Panel2, Panel3, ... my main windows consist of two or more panels, for examples Window1 consists of Panel1 and Panel2, Window2 consists of Panel3 and Panel2, ... They are all one below the other and it might happen that I have to add or remove something from a panel, so that it grows or shrinks. Do I have to use a TableLayout to keep them aligned? Or is there an option that tells my Panel1 that it should be position where Panel2 ends?

Update: I forgot to mention that I'm working on a desktop application. When researching both TableLayoutPanel and GridLayoutPanel I read that made a difference.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to tell Panel2 to start where panel1 ends.  However, "have to use a TableLayout" is not true either.  You could use manual repositioning or a flow layout panel for example. Off-hand, from your brief description it sounds like a flow layout panel might fit the bill here better than a table layout control.

Comment: I agree. This sounds like a flow layout containing autosizing panels.

Comment: thanks for the idea, I only had a brief look at a FlowLayout, and it seems to put the panels in a row as long as there is space, right? But I want my panels to be below each other, no matter how much space there is on the right side. Don't the rows of a TableLayout resize automatically depending on the content?

Comment: There are two properties of the FlowLayoutPanel that help here: `.FlowDirection` (so you can flow it down instead of across) and `.WrapContents` (though you probably won't need this).  There are other interesting properties like the space between items etc.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx for all the properties and methods.

Comment: thx I'll have a look at it! I add the information that I work on a desktop application to my question. Does it make a difference?

Comment: FlowLayoutPanel is a WinForm control so it's good to go on the desktop.  But really, you can just try it.